# Moving chess pieces in native javascript

Tags: javascript, chess

I'm having some problems with my assignment, which was to make chess pieces move freely across the board without the use of ids in native javascript. I have managed to set them on board and have also tried with getting coordinates from clicking on a piece, then getting coordinates from clicking somewhere on board and assigning the chosen piece those newly acquired coordinates, but nothing seems to work correctly.
I'd really appreciate some help :)

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body 
    {
    padding: 20px;
    }
h1
    {
    text-align: center
    }
table 
    {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
td
    {
    width: 40px; 
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    }
.up
    {
    border-top-style: hidden;
    border-left-style: hidden;
    border-right-style: hidden;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold
    }
.down
    {
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-left-style: hidden;
    border-right-style: hidden;
    border-bottom-style: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold
    }
.left
    {
    border-top-style: hidden;
    border-left-style: hidden;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold
    }
.right
    {
    border-top-style: hidden;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-style: hidden;
    border-bottom-style: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold
    }
.gray
    {
    background-color: gray;
    }
.white
    {
    background-color: white;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script> // chessboard
document.write("<h1>Game</h1>");
document.write("<table><tr class=up><td></td>");
for (var k=0; k<=7; k++){ //letters on top, 97 is a, 104 is h
    document.write("<td>" + String.fromCharCode(k+97) + "</td>");
}
document.write("</tr>");
for (var j=8; j>0; j--){ //numbers dropping on sides
    document.write("<tr onclick='indexRow(this)'><td class=left>" + j + "</td>");
    if((j%2)==0){
        for (var i=0; i<8; i++){
            if((i%2)==0){
                document.write('<td onclick="indexCell(this)" class=white></td>'); //grab index
            } else{
                document.write('<td onclick="indexCell(this)" class=gray></td>'); //grab index
            };
        }
    } else{
        for (var i=0; i<8; i++){
            if((i%2)==0){
                document.write('<td onclick="indexCell(this)" class=gray></td>'); //grab index
            } else{
                document.write('<td onclick="indexCell(this)" class=white></td>'); //grab index
            };
        }
    };
    document.write("<td class=right>" + j + "</td>");
}
document.write("<tr class=down><td></td>");
for (var k=0; k<=7; k++){ //letters on top,97 is a, 104 is h
    document.write("<td>" + String.fromCharCode(k+97) + "</td>");
}
document.write("</tr></table>");

//pieces
var pieces=new Array( //pieces
                new Array(" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "),
                new Array(" ","&#9814"," "," ","&#9812","&#9813","&#9815","&#9816","&#9814"),
                new Array(" ","&#9817","&#9817","&#9817"," "," ","&#9817","&#9817","&#9817"),
                new Array(" "," "," "," "," ","&#9817"," "," "," "),
                new Array(" "," "," "," ","&#9817"," "," "," "," "),
                new Array(" "," "," "," ","&#9816"," "," ","&#9815"," "),
                new Array(" "," "," ","&#9822"," "," "," "," "," "),
                new Array(" ","&#9823","&#9823","&#9823","&#9822","&#9823","&#9823","&#9823","&#9823"),
                new Array(" ","&#9820"," ","&#9821","&#9818","&#9819","&#9821"," ","&#9820")
            );

//sets up the board
function setUp(){
    for (i = 1; i <=8; i++){
        for (j = 1; j <=8; j++){
            document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[j].getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML = pieces[j][i];
        }
    }
}
setUp();
//attempts with making things move
var clickedon = false;
var save_x = 0;
var save_y = 0;
var piece = 0;
var _x = 0;
var _y = 0;

//gets cell index
function indexCell(x)
{
//alert("Cell index is: " + x.cellIndex);
_x = x.cellIndex;
if(clickedon == false)
{
if(pieces[_x][_y] != " ")
{  
    figura = pieces[_x][_y];
    save_x = _x;
    save_y = _y;
    clickedon = true;
    alert(piece)    
}  
}
else
{
if(pieces[_x][_y] == " ")
{
    pieces[save_x][save_y] = " ";
    pieces[_x][_y] = piece;
    setUp();
    clickedon = false
}       
}
}
//grabs row index
function indexRow(y){
//alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
_y = y.rowIndex;
}

</script>
</body>
```

Edit: I've now posted the version with my attempts at making pieces move and with numbers and letters around.

Comment: "nothing seems to work correctly" isn't much of a hint. **HOW** does this not work?

Comment: Look for css `position:absolute` in google. That would be required to move any DOM element to a given coordinate. This is all the help you can get with the code and information you have posted.

Comment: I don't see any code related to capturing clicks.

Comment: do these pieces have to be animated or can they just disappear and reappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is set an `onclick` event for each of the table cells, and have several global variables to hold the state of the chess board.

So here is what I would suggest trying:

```
var state = false //false if no piece has been selected
var currentPiece;
var currentCell;

var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
   cells[i].onclick = function(){
       getCell(this);
   };
}

function getCell(that) {
    if(!state) { //this means if the state is false (i.e. no piece selected
        state = true; //piece has been selected
        currentPiece = that.innerHTML; //get the current piece selected
        currentCell = that; //get the current cell selection
    }
    else { //else, you are moving a piece
        that.innerHTML = currentPiece; //Set the selected space to the piece that was grabbed
        currentCell.innerHTML = ""; //remove the piece from its old location
        state = false; //piece has been placed, so set state back to false
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this is just a rough layout of how I would handle this. I didn't take into account type of pieces or certain exceptions or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
 var restartBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON"),
  mainDiv = document.createElement("DIV");

 restartBtn.innerHTML = "RESTART";
 restartBtn.id = "restartBtn";
 mainDiv.id = "chessboard";
 document.body.appendChild(restartBtn);
 document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
 restartBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  reset();
 });

 function reset() {
  document.getElementById("chessboard").innerHTML = "";
  chessboardGame();
 }


 var chessboardGame = function () {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
   var colorClass, child, grandChild;

   for (var j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
    if ((i + j) % 2 === 0) {
     colorClass = "black";
    } else {
     colorClass = "white";
    }

    child = document.createElement("DIV");
    child.id = "column-" + i + j;
    grandChild = document.createElement("DIV");
    child.classList.add("box");
    child.classList.add(colorClass);
    child.classList.add("chess-column");
    grandChild.id = "coin-" + i + j;
    grandChild.classList.add("border-column");

    document.getElementById("chessboard").appendChild(child);


    if (i < 3) {
     document.getElementById("column-" + i + j).appendChild(grandChild);
     grandChild.classList.add("white-coin");
     grandChild.classList.add("black-border");
    } else if (i > 6) {
     document.getElementById("column-" + i + j).appendChild(grandChild);
     grandChild.classList.add("black-coin");
     grandChild.classList.add("white-border");
    }
   }

  }
  var chessColumns = document.getElementsByClassName("chess-column");
  for (var k = 0; k < chessColumns.length; k++) {

   chessColumns[k].onclick = function (e) {

    var el = chessColumns[0];
    while (el) {
     if (el.tagName === "DIV") {
      el.classList.remove("red-border");
     }
     el = el.nextSibling;
    }
    onColumnClick(e, this);
   };
  }

 };




 function onColumnClick(e, el) {
  el.classList.add("red-border");
  if (el.children[0]) {

   var currentActiveColumn = getActiveColumn();
   if (currentActiveColumn && currentActiveColumn !== el) {
    setActiveColumn(currentActiveColumn);
    setActiveCoin(currentActiveColumn.children[0]);
   } else {
    setActiveColumn(el);
    setActiveCoin(el.children[0]);
   }
  }

  var activeColumn = getActiveColumn(),
   activeCoin = getActiveCoin();

  if (activeColumn && activeColumn !== e.currentTarget) {
   if (Math.abs(activeColumn.offsetLeft - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft) > 80 || Math.abs(activeColumn.offsetTop - e.currentTarget.offsetTop) > 80) {
    alert("Move not allowed!");
    e.currentTarget.classList.remove("red-border");
    activeCoin.parentNode.classList.add("red-border");
   } else {
    moveCoin(activeColumn, el, activeCoin);

   }

  }
 }
 chessboardGame();
 function moveCoin(activeItem, targetItem, coin) {
  if (targetItem.firstChild) {
   var activeItemClassList = coin.classList,
    targetItemClassList = targetItem.firstChild.classList;

   if (activeItemClassList[1] === targetItemClassList[1]) {
    alert("Move not allowed!");
    targetItem.classList.remove("red-border");
    activeItem.classList.add("red-border");
    return;
   }
  }

  while (activeItem.firstChild) {
   activeItem.removeChild(activeItem.firstChild);
  }
  while (targetItem.firstChild) {
   alert("Good Move there!");
   targetItem.removeChild(targetItem.firstChild);
  }
  targetItem.appendChild(coin);
  setActiveColumn(targetItem);
 }

 function setActiveColumn(el) {
  this.activeColumn = el;
 }

 function getActiveColumn() {
  return this.activeColumn;
 }

 function setActiveCoin(coin) {
  this.activeCoin = coin;
 }

 function getActiveCoin() {
  return this.activeCoin;
 }
});
```

```css
#chessboard {
    width: 640px;
    height: 640px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    position: relative;

}
.black {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #333333;
    font-size:50px;
    text-align:center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.white {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size:50px;
    text-align:center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.black-coin{
    background: black;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin: 37% auto;
    transition: left .5s ease-in, top .5s ease-in;
}

.white-border{
    border: 2px solid white;
}

.white-coin{
    background: white;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 37% auto;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: left .5s ease-in, top .5s ease-in;
}

.black-border{
    border: 2px solid black;
}


.red-border{border: 2px solid red; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>CHESSBOARD</title>

</head>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I Have created a chessboard with pieces using javascript,where you can move the pieces restricted to 2 steps and also i have created a restart button to move the pieces to there initial places on clicking the button i.e it restarts the game.